# app opens a crash dialog on device startup

Tags: android, crash, parse-platform

Every time when I open my device I see this message:

Link for the image (I don't have enough reputation): https://i.stack.imgur.com/TceMS.png

Logcat:

```
    12-19 11:57:47.914: E/com.parse.PushService(18423): The Parse push service cannot start because     Parse.initialize has not yet been called. If you call Parse.initialize from an Activity's onCreate, that call should instead be in the Application.onCreate. Be sure your Application class is registered in your AndroidManifest.xml with the android:name property of your <application> tag.
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.parse.PushService@419934e8 with Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION flg=0x10 pkg=com.idonaveh.guess cmp=com.idonaveh.guess/com.parse.PushService (has extras) }: java.lang.RuntimeException: applicationContext is null. You must call Parse.initialize(context, applicationId, clientKey) before using the Parse library.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2859)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:162)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1461)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: applicationContext is null. You must call Parse.initialize(context, applicationId, clientKey) before using the Parse library.
    at com.parse.Parse.checkContext(Parse.java:634)
    at com.parse.Parse.getApplicationContext(Parse.java:236)
    at com.parse.ManifestInfo.getContext(ManifestInfo.java:322)
    at com.parse.ManifestInfo.getPackageName(ManifestInfo.java:326)
    at com.parse.ManifestInfo.getIntentReceivers(ManifestInfo.java:131)
    at com.parse.ManifestInfo.hasIntentReceiver(ManifestInfo.java:123)
    at com.parse.ManifestInfo.getPushUsesBroadcastReceivers(ManifestInfo.java:174)
    at com.parse.PushService.wipeRoutingAndUpgradePushStateIfNeeded(PushService.java:449)
    at com.parse.PushService.onStartCommand(PushService.java:430)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2842)
    ... 10 more
```

Parse initialize:

```
Parse.initialize(this, "Application ID", "Client Key");
    ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
    installation.saveInBackground();
```

It pops every time that I open my device... what to do?

Comment: The crashlog speaks for itself. You must call Parse.initialize(context, applicationId, clientKey) before using the Parse library.

Comment: Sorry I didn't post the code... Anyway @Carnal every activity has Parse.inizialize...

Comment: Show us the code where you use Parse.initialize

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410439/how-to-initialize-the-parse-com-code-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410439/how-to-initialize-the-parse-com-code-in-android)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should call this in your `Application` class, in order just do it once.

```
import com.parse.Parse;
import android.app.Application;

public class YourApplicationName extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, "PARSE_APPLICATION_ID", "PARSE_CLIENT_KEY");
  }
}
```

In the Manifest declare it like this

```
<application
    android:name="yourpackagename.YourApplicationName"
.
.
.
```

Or if you want to use your approach and call it in every `Activity`, you will have to use `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this`.

Comment: the `onCreate()` method never gets called in `MyApplicationName.java` class.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using Parse.
If so, you have to make sure to set it up right before you can use it in your app.
Make sure you've followed all the steps documented in the [QuickStart guide](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/existing) from Parse.
As the error message informs you that you haven't called the initiaze method of Parse, make sure you do this in your Application subclass that you have to create by yourself:

```
Parse.initialize(this, "APPLICATION ID", "CLIENT KEY");
```

After you did this, you can test Parse to check if everything is configured as it should with the Test the SDK section at the bottom of the QuickStart guide.

Comment: Are you sure that the Parse.initialize method gets called? You have to set your subclass of the Application class as android:name in the AndroidManifest like this:   <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
android:name="com.example.MyApplication">
      <... /> 
  </application>

Answer (score 0):

I too had a similar error message.

I believe that one can initialise parse using

Parse.initialize(this, "PARSE_APPLICATION_ID", "PARSE_CLIENT_KEY");

only once in a whole app.i.e you cannot initialise parse again and again in each activity or fragment.
I recommend initialising parse in the main activity and do not repeat the initialise code anywhere else.